# making pink noise (1/f) using list of frequencies

Tags: matlab, fft, octave, noise, noise-generator

making pink noise (1/f) using list of frequencies

I would like to see what type of noise I would get if I used just the frequency in my voice. I created a matlab/octave array using fft to get the **[frequency,amplitude,phase]** to reproduce my vocal signal.

I would like to take this file/data and use it to create pink noise (1/f). Of course when I use 1/f for the frequency the numbers become very small does anyone have any ideas how to use my own vocal frequencies that I get from doing a fft in matlab to create pink noise (1/f).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do the trick: compute the mean power in your spectrum from the amplitude A = A(f), where f is the frequency.

```
P = mean(A.^2);
```

Spread that over your frequency range:

```
N = length(f);
invfnorm = 1./[1:N];
Anew = sqrt(P*invfnorm/sum(invfnorm));
```

Anew has the property of having the same total power density as the original spectrum, and power decaying as 1/f.

Substitute Anew for A and inverse FFT your new spectrum to generate the new waveform.

Comment: in you answer what does N represent?  I know "A" is the amplitude of each frequency, but what is N?

Comment: missed and now edited that - it's the (complex) length of your spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct, what you are doing is generating noise based on a 1/f frequency. However if you read the following article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink_noise  the frequencies are the same except that the power spectral density is `S` is proportional to `1/f`. Hence you should not be generating noise of frequency 1/f.

I would suggest reading [this page](http://www.firstpr.com.au/dsp/pink-noise/) for the necessary algorithms.

However if the problem you are facing is that the volume is too low, try amplifying the synthesized noise by multiplying the result by a factor ex.: `pinkNoise = pinkNoise * 100`